# How to filter ng-options

Tags: angularjs

A customer sees all of there documents on a table. Documents has its own service call, I have select boxes that they can use to filter them. One of the options is Location. There is a lot of locations in the database, I do not want them all to be available, I only want the ones that match the locations of there specific documents.

Documents JSON

```
[{
    "$id": "1",
    "DocumentId": 75,
    "DocumentDate": "2015-01-31T22:00:00",
    "DocumentUrl": "/Files/Black Elk-Invoices-None-January 2015.pdf",
    "UploadDate": "2015-02-20T05:25:22.737",
    "UploadedBy": "Rudy Sanchez",
    "CompanyName": "Black_Elk",
    "Plant": "None",
    "Type": "Invoices",
    "Location": "None",
    "CounterParty": "None",
    "Pipe": "None",
    "CompanyId": 1,
    "PlantId": 1,
    "TypeId": 2,
    "LocationId": 1,
    "PipeId": 1,
    "CounterPartyId": 1
}, {
    "$id": "2",
    "DocumentId": 78,
    "DocumentDate": "2015-04-30T22:00:00",
    "DocumentUrl": "/Files/Saratoga-Processing Statements-None-April 2015.pdf",
    "UploadDate": "2015-02-20T05:29:34.527",
    "UploadedBy": "Rudy Sanchez",
    "CompanyName": "Saratoga",
    "Plant": "Baytown",
    "Type": "Processing Statements",
    "Location": "None",
    "CounterParty": "None",
    "Pipe": "None",
    "CompanyId": 2,
    "PlantId": 2,
    "TypeId": 3,
    "LocationId": 1,
    "PipeId": 1,
    "CounterPartyId": 1
}, {
    "$id": "3",
    "DocumentId": 79,
    "DocumentDate": "2015-08-31T22:00:00",
    "DocumentUrl": "/Files/Black Elk-Sales Data-None-August 2015.pdf",
    "UploadDate": "2015-02-20T05:29:45.147",
    "UploadedBy": "Rudy Sanchez",
    "CompanyName": "Black_Elk",
    "Plant": "None",
    "Type": "Sales Data",
    "Location": "None",
    "CounterParty": "None",
    "Pipe": "None",
    "CompanyId": 1,
    "PlantId": 1,
    "TypeId": 4,
    "LocationId": 1,
    "PipeId": 1,
    "CounterPartyId": 1
}, {
    "$id": "4",
    "DocumentId": 80,
    "DocumentDate": "2015-02-28T22:00:00",
    "DocumentUrl": "/Files/Black Elk-Invoices-CounterParty A-February 2015.pdf",
    "UploadDate": "2015-02-20T05:30:25.507",
    "UploadedBy": "Rudy Sanchez",
    "CompanyName": "Black_Elk",
    "Plant": "None",
    "Type": "Invoices",
    "Location": "None",
    "CounterParty": "CounterParty A",
    "Pipe": "None",
    "CompanyId": 1,
    "PlantId": 1,
    "TypeId": 2,
    "LocationId": 1,
    "PipeId": 1,
    "CounterPartyId": 2
}]
```

Locations JSON

```
[{
    "$id": "1",
    "LocationId": 1,
    "LocationName": "None",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "6",
    "LocationId": 6,
    "LocationName": "BS 32 (G)",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "7",
    "LocationId": 7,
    "LocationName": "MP 140 (T)",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "8",
    "LocationId": 8,
    "LocationName": "HI A 442",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "9",
    "LocationId": 9,
    "LocationName": "HI  A 443",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "10",
    "LocationId": 10,
    "LocationName": "HI A 571/ 574",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "11",
    "LocationId": 11,
    "LocationName": "EC 33CF",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "12",
    "LocationId": 12,
    "LocationName": "EC 33D",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "13",
    "LocationId": 13,
    "LocationName": "EC 81/84",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "14",
    "LocationId": 14,
    "LocationName": "WC 142/ 178",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "15",
    "LocationId": 15,
    "LocationName": "WC 20/45",
    "Documents": null
}, {
    "$id": "16",
    "LocationId": 16,
    "LocationName": "MP 25/35",
    "Documents": null
} {
    "$id": "33",
    "LocationId": 33,
    "LocationName": "VR 16",
    "Documents": null
}]
```

Service Calls

```
$scope.docTypes = Type.query(function () { console.log($scope.docTypes) });
$scope.docLocations = Location.query(function () { console.log($scope.docLocations) });
```

SelectBox

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="search.Location"
                    ng-options="l.LocationName as l.LocationName for l in docLocations">
                {{l.Location}}
            </select>
            <p class="help-block" style="text-align:center">Select Location</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To be clear: are you trying to filter all the documents in the table with a single select input that only lists a location if it is listed by one or more documents?

Comment: correct. I dont want to give the user more options than he needs to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQgd5TTzGft50EnMGhMN?p=preview) demonstrating the below technique.

**First:** You need to filter your locations in your controller and `push` to a new array that populates your `<select>` field.

```
$scope.locationsList = [];

angular.forEach($scope.documents, function(documents, key) {
    angular.forEach($scope.locations, function(locations, key) {        
    if (locations.LocationId == documents.LocationId)
      $scope.locationsList.push({id: locations.LocationId,  LocationName: locations.LocationName})
    });
})
```

**Second:** You need to filter out duplicate locations. The awesome [angular-ui/ui-utils](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils) has a module just for this purpose. Follow the installation instructions and add it to your:

`var app = angular.module('ngApp', ['ui.utils']);`

Then you can simply add a unique filter to your `ng-options` like so:

```
ng-model="selectedFeature" ng-options="location.LocationId as location.LocationName for location in locationsList | unique: 'LocationName'">
```

I hope this helps.